# Laptop battery only updated at boot

Tags: boot, laptop, battery

I use Lenovo Yoga  910-13ikb. So I found that my laptop battery couldn't gauge it's power percentage. At first I open it at 67% and after using for a while it keep at 67%. But then after restart it shows 30%. I try to charge it but it still stuck at 30% for a while. I restart it again, and it shows 83%. Seems like the power only updated when the laptop first boot.

First I thought it just driver issue. I updated all my driver but still the same. Tried to reinstall the driver but nothing work. I even try using Ubuntu (previously using Windows10) but not working. I tried with pushing the power button for 2 minutes, as internet suggested but it's not giving any difference. I try to take off the battery and push the power button again but still the same. I even change the battery (the battery life is already low like 30% of  it's prime) but the problem persist, but now I got the battery prediction. It said `Discharging (31%, 136 hours and 51 minutes` which is weird because It shouldn't last that long. I waited to see if it's working now, but the battery still only updated when boot.

I checked that my Time always change in BIOS. I wonder if the battery thing happen because of broken CMOS

Any idea what is actually broken?